# Entendendo o conceito de export symbols em bibliotecas compartilhadas

Tags: c, c++, dll, diretivas-de-compilação

Estou lendo sobre esse conceito de exportar elementos para fora de uma biblioteca compartilhada (DLL ou SO).

Estou lendo [essa](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) publicação existente na Wiki do GCC.

O último exemplo da publicação é esse:

```
// Generic helper definitions for shared library support
#if defined _WIN32 || defined __CYGWIN__
  #define FOX_HELPER_DLL_IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
  #define FOX_HELPER_DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
  #define FOX_HELPER_DLL_LOCAL
#else
  #if __GNUC__ >= 4
    #define FOX_HELPER_DLL_IMPORT __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
    #define FOX_HELPER_DLL_EXPORT __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
    #define FOX_HELPER_DLL_LOCAL  __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))
  #else
    #define FOX_HELPER_DLL_IMPORT
    #define FOX_HELPER_DLL_EXPORT
    #define FOX_HELPER_DLL_LOCAL
  #endif
#endif

// Now we use the generic helper definitions above to define FOX_API and FOX_LOCAL.
// FOX_API is used for the public API symbols. It either DLL imports or DLL exports (or does nothing for static build)
// FOX_LOCAL is used for non-api symbols.

#ifdef FOX_DLL // defined if FOX is compiled as a DLL
  #ifdef FOX_DLL_EXPORTS // defined if we are building the FOX DLL (instead of using it)
    #define FOX_API FOX_HELPER_DLL_EXPORT
  #else
    #define FOX_API FOX_HELPER_DLL_IMPORT
  #endif // FOX_DLL_EXPORTS
  #define FOX_LOCAL FOX_HELPER_DLL_LOCAL
#else // FOX_DLL is not defined: this means FOX is a static lib.
  #define FX_API
  #define FOX_LOCAL
#endif // FOX_DLL
```

Minha dúvida está no começo da segunda parte, mais precisamente na linha:

`#ifdef FOX_DLL // defined if FOX is compiled as a DLL`

Aqui está sendo feito uma verificação se a macro FOX_DLL foi definida. Mas em que momento no código essa macro é definida? Estou vendo o teste `#ifdef` dela mas não estou vendo a definição dela em lugar nenhum.

E o nome? É de livre escolha? Existe limitações para a escolha do nome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalmente isto é definido pela compilação. Então normalmente ela é definida pelo Make, outra ferramenta de construção do software ou pelo *script* que chama o compilador ou ainda pela linha de comando simples do GCC.

Existem outras opções mas pela descrição é uma definição de símbolo externa ao código.

A [opção do compilador](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) que permite fazer isto é o `-DFOX_DLL`.

É um símbolo qualquer, seguindo as regras de qualquer símbolo, tendo a certeza que não vai conflitar com nada, pode criar o que quiser, de preferência algo que faça sentido.

Comment: E quanto ao nome? É de livre escolha?

Comment: Sim, é um símbolo qualquer, seguindo as regras de qualquer símbolo, tendo a certeza que não vai conflitar com nada, pode criar o que quiser.